# How can i convert Map of Strings and Object to a Map of Strings and List

Tags: java, dictionary

I have method that should return `Map<Strings, List<String>>` but in the mean time my method gives me a `Map<Strings, Object>`, I want to transfer the values of object into a List of Strings.

Here is the current code:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    static Map<String, List<String>> getQueryParameters(JsonObject inputJsonObject) {

        JsonArray parameters = inputJsonObject.getJsonArray("parameters");

        Optional<JsonObject> queryParameters = parameters.stream().
            filter(JsonObject.class::isInstance).
            map(JsonObject.class::cast).
            filter(jsonObject -> jsonObject.getJsonObject("queryParameters") != null).
            map(item -> item.getJsonObject("queryParameters")).findFirst();

        Map<String, Object> paramMap = queryParameters.get().getMap();
```

`paramMap` contains  key and value , values could be an arrays of integers
so I want to put them into the map below:

```
 Map<String, List<String>> mystore = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

My solution is this which did not work correctly

```
 Map<String, List<String>> mystore = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();

        Map<String, Object> paramMap = queryParameters.get().getMap();

        Iterator it = paramMap.entrySet().iterator();

          while (it.hasNext()) {
            String key = it.next().toString();
            if (!mystore.containsKey(key)) ;

            mystore.put(key, new LinkedList<String>());

            mystore.get(key).add(it.next().toString());
        }
```

I was a key holding another key as value and is just a mix up , any suggestions?
After debuging what happens i see that mystore holds both "key and value" together as a key and value it hold the next "key and value as value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, Object> next = iterator.next();
        String key = next.getKey();
        Object value = next.getValue();
        if (!mystore.containsKey(key)) mystore.put(key, new LinkedList<String>());
        mystore.get(key).add(value.toString());
    }
```

Comment: iterator.nexr() need to be casted like this (Map.Entry<String, Object>) and also i think you mean it.next  as was written in while statement

Comment: it.next returns the the next key-value entry of the map. No cast should be needed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not writing a program for you, but instead help you in finding a problem. You are confused with `Entry`. If you are using IDE, you should solve it easier. Look for this line :

```
String key = it.next().toString();
```

`Entry` has a K,V pair. The iterator returns an `EntrySet` and thus usage to get key is `it.next().getKey()` and `it.next().getValue()`

Now that you have a correct key, please go on debugging. Instead of putting and getting and manipulating in below lines of your code. Put with correct value instead?

**Yours:**

```
mystore.put(key, new LinkedList<String>());
mystore.get(key).add(it.next().toString());
```

**What about?**:

```
Entry entry = it.next();
//Get key and value here. DO coding using Entry's methods
List<String> ll = new LinkedList<String>();
ll.add(value)
mystore.put(key, ll);
```

Tip: Always have the Javadoc or reference documentation handy for knowing more. That's how you learn the language. Refer:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html